# ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: string, python-2.7, floating-point

I have a problem with the following code:

```
inputf = open('test.dat', 'r')
lines = inputf.readlines()
rico_clus_e = []
for line in lines:
    line.split()
    print line
    if (line[0] != '#'):
        rico_clus_e.append(float(line[4]))
inputf.close()
```

My test.dat file is:

```
# specn rico_all        rico_all_e  rico_clus   rico_clus_e rico_farclust   rico_far_e  extin
a119        1.07038692  0.11109547  0.61473431  0.15063627  0.32590239      0.14777812  0.207
```

And this gives the following output in my terminal:

```
# specn rico_all        rico_all_e  rico_clus   rico_clus_e rico_farclust   rico_far_e  extin

a119        1.07038692  0.11109547  0.61473431  0.15063627  0.32590239      0.14777812  0.207

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    rico_clus_e.append(float(line[4]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I'm quite confused by this. It had nothing to do with spaces, I checked them all. And if you change 4 by 1, 2 or 3 this works, so it must have something to do with the test.dat file, but I can't seem to figure out how. I'm using python 2.7.3.

Comment: The representation (hint: `repr()`) of the element is...?

Comment: The representation is ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line.split()` on its own does nothing to `line`. You must store the result of the method call and use that instead.

Comment: But why does it work for the other values? Changing 4 to 3, 2 or 1 does work... For number 3, the representation is '9', for element 2 it's '1'

Comment: That's because `line[3]` is `'9'`, and `line[2]` is `'1'`. And `line[0]` is `'a'`.

Comment: Okay, I understand your response now. It thought that `'9'` was something internal, but it just refers to the string. `line = line.split()` is the thing that did the trick. Thx!